# Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `put` with ng-file-upload

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-storage, ng-file-upload

### Angular upload and view image posted to firebase with ng-file-upload

I am using firebase with angular. I have put a photo into firebase storage.
I have the photo url.

In my view I can see the image with angular ng-file-upload making:
ngf-src="http://url_photo"

Next, I just need to save the photo again.
When use the UploadFile method below I get  an error because the file is not a blob.

If I use "Upload.urlToBlob" method from ng-file-upload to convert the url to blog, firebase throw a CORS origin error. So, I can´t do that.

What could I to solve it?

[image]

//markup

```
<div class="image-upload">
    <label for="file-input">
        <img class="drop-box-filled-totem" ngf-src="mobilePhoto||'//ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png'"/>
    </label>
   <button 
      id="file-input"
      ng-model="mobilePhoto"
      ngf-fix-orientation="true"
      ngf-select="selectPhoto($event, $file)"
      ngf-capture="'camera'"
      accept="image/*">
  </button>
                      
</div>
```

//controller

```
var uploadFile=function(file){
    var bucketName='Photos/'+$scope.user.PRONT+'/Foto';
    var storageRef=firebase.storage().ref(bucketName);
    var storage=$firebaseStorage(storageRef);
    var uploadTask=storage.$put(file); -->throw error
}

var getPhotoUrl=function(pront){
    var bucketName='Photos/'+pront+'/Foto';
    var ref=firebase.database().ref(bucketName);
    var url=$firebaseObject(ref)
    url.$loaded().then(function(){
      $scope.mobilePhoto=url.imageUrl;
    })
}
getPhotoUrl($scope.user.PRONT)
```

Comment: Show the code that invokes the `uploadFile` function.